# How to configure a Cocoapod with a (local) framework dependency (podspec & xcodeproj)?

Tags: xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

After much reading, I'm more confused than ever... I'm trying to convert a client SDK project into a pod (and/or SPM). Prior to this, it was using a podfile to create and link to a local framework dependency (a podspec in the repo but outside the xcode project). This is because the SDK shares an interface with the client apps that uses it. The depedency graph looks like this:

```
ExampleApp
|- InterfaceFramework
|-SDK
   |- InterfaceFramework
```

I am unclear on how to set this up so that `SDK` is a pod that can be built by itself (to produce the framework to be used by external clients). It needs to know where the `InterfaceFramework` is or I get `No such module` errors. But this `InterfaceFramework` is generated by ExampleApp's Podfile...?

What is the right way to go about configuring this??

Bonus karma for SPM instructions as well! (Though if I can sus cocoapods then hopefully that will follow)

Comment: See https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html

Comment: Been there. That doesn’t really cover it. I’m trying to make a private pod that (also) builds as a framework binary that interfaces to another (shared) private framework.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the first (of many) things that perhaps Cocoapods.org doesn't make so clear is that if a Pod you are making has dependencies, then it's correct for it to have it's own Podfile. In other words, a cocoapod can use cocoapods... Perhaps I'm being daft but that wasn't immediately intuitive to me.

That Podfile is *just* to get your pod code to build (compile/link) locally *which is a requirement* of pushing the podspec (whether it be to a private podspec repo or the CP public one). Note, when your pod code is pulled in by a client project, it just pulls your code. It doesn't do anything with pod's podfile and it doesn't package up those dependencies. The client app using your pod will need to take care of them (in their podfile, manually framework import, etc)

**Sanity check:** If your pod doesn't have any dependencies then it doesn't need representation in the podfile (as a target).  BUT...if you have a Demo Project in your pod repo there will still be a podfile for that (to pull your pod code).

Note to newbies/absent minded: A single podfile covers all the targets in your workspace - in this case your pod's code and the demo app. These "targets" are independent (unless you nest them or something).

**NEXT:** Podspec's don't tell you where to get the dependencies, just that your pod has them. BUT...the `pod lib lint` or `pod repo push` validations WILL look for the dependency in whatever podspec repos you specify (defaulting to just the public CP one). Fine for public depedencies but for local unhosted development ones it won't be able to find them.  It's a bit lame IMO that your podfile can say a depedency is local (ie "development pod") but the podspec validator can't be told that. This is perhaps because CP was built initially for open source projects...

So...you'll need to push your local dependencies' podspecs to your private podspec repo as well. This means the dependencies repos need to be accessible by whoever is using your pod.

If you really (really) want them local-only on your machine (if not skip this paragraph...trust me), then you'll have to set up *another* private podspec repo locally, in a folder, just for the dependencies. The reason you need another private podspec repo is because you surely still want your pod's podspec available remotely (ie non-locally) or else no one would be able to pull your pod, defeating the point of having one...

**Sanity check:** So...ignoring the above paragraph... your private podspec repo will have several entries: the podspec for your pod, and one for each of your private dependencies.

**NEXT**...you're almost there!...When you want to lint/push your pod's podspec, you need to specify the list of podspec repos via `--sources:repo1,repo2,...`. It's not smart enough to just use your system registered ones. Boo.

Also you may want to use a medley of vaguely defined seemingly overlaping and counter-intuitive flags to reign back the validation beast because, after all, you don't really care what CP thinks of your private pod code as long as It Just Works™.  Here's an example from mine...

`pod repo push MyPrivatePodSpecRepo MyShinyNewPod.podspec --skip-tests --private --allow-warnings --skip-import-validation --sources=git@github.com:SnazzyCo/MyPrivatePodSpecRepo.git,https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`

**A few more notes...**

`--skip-import-validation` — This doesn't apply to the depedencies, just the pod itself.

You'd think `--include-podspecs=MyLocalUnHostedPods/**/*` would save you all this trouble but it doesn't.

I think `--private` is actually only for `pod lib lint` (`pod repo push` has a `--no-private` flag) but I'm too scared to remove it...

`pod repo push` basically does a `pod lib lint` so save yourself the trouble of the later.  Except you can run `pod lib lint --quick` to just check syntax (I think)

**FINALLY:**

- Don't forget to have the client apps using your private pod to add a `source 'urlToMyPrivatePodspecRepo'` up top of their podfile.
- I can't remember why but in order for the DemoApp in my pod repo to use the pod correctly I had to replace the `pod MyShinyNewPod` to `podspec :path => 'MyShinyNewPod.podspec'`